# How to inference large models (neural networks) in production?

Tags: python, deep-learning, server, pytorch, production

I want to use few large neural networks (large I mean: > 5GB) in production. It is kind of handmade production because im not an expert and i do it for my own. I have my own server with RTX 4090 and i have more than 10 different large models. And I want to have dicrease inference time (as much as possible). And the biggest problem it is time of initilization because it is about 10-20 seconds (for comparing: generate time is about 2 seconds). I didn't find anything about how to optimize that moment. The one moment which I made up is to keep the model in GPU memory, but it has minus. When user want to use another neural network (not model which currently in GPU memory) I should again init another model and agaign waste time. But this way is better than nothing...

So I have 2 questions:

1. Is it safe for my GPU if i will keep model in GPU memory (24 hours in day even when there are no requests from users)?
2. Do you know better solutions? Maybe it is possible to keep model in usual RAM and load model to GPU from RAM, not from SSD? Will it be faster than loading model from SSD? Or pls tell any advices or any solutions, I don't know how can I optimize this process.

Thank you very much!

The one moment which I made up is to keep the model in GPU memory, but it has minus. When user want to use another neural network (not model which currently in GPU memory) I should again init another model and agaign waste time. But this way is better than nothing..

Comment: Maybe there are any best pracitce or any articles which I can read about this moment? Because I didn't find anything (yeah, maybe Im bad in searching)